# Can't remove slug in url

Tags: slug

I need remove slug **movie** from site.com/movie/mymoviename

I've tried remove 'slug' => 'movie', 'with_front' => FALSE,), from code, but this don't help's me.
Here a code

```
    <?php 

/* Movies post type*/

function post_type_movies() {
register_post_type(
                    'movies', 
                    array( 'public' => true,
                            'publicly_queryable' => true,
                            'has_archive' => true, 
                            'hierarchical' => false,
                            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/movie.png',
                            'labels'=>array(
                                        'name' => _x('Movies', 'post type general name'),
                                        'singular_name' => _x('Movie', 'post type singular name'),
                                        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Movies'),
                                        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Movie'),
                                        'edit_item' => __('Edit Movie'),
                                        'new_item' => __('New Movie'),
                                        'view_item' => __('View Movie'),
                                        'search_items' => __('Search Movies'),
                                        'not_found' =>  __('No Movies found'),
                                        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Movie found in Trash'), 
                                        'parent_item_colon' => ''
                                        ),                           
                            'show_ui' => true,
                            'menu_position'=>5,
                            'query_var' => true,
                            'rewrite' => TRUE,
                            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'movie', 'with_front' => FALSE,),
                            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'mytheme_add_box',
                            'supports' => array(
                                        'title',
                                        'thumbnail',
                                        'comments',
                                        'editor'
                                        )
                            ) 
                    );
                } 
add_action('init', 'post_type_movies');

/* Movie genre taxonomy */

function create_movie_genre_taxonomy() 
{
$labels = array(
                              'name' => _x( 'Movie Genre', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                              'singular_name' => _x( 'movie-genre', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search movie genres' ),
                              'all_items' => __( 'All movie genres' ),
                              'parent_item' => __( 'Parent movie genre' ),
                              'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent movie genre:' ),
                              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit movie genre' ), 
                              'update_item' => __( 'Update movie genre' ),
                              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Movie Genre' ),
                              'new_item_name' => __( 'New movie genre Name' ),
);  
register_taxonomy('movie-genre',array('movies'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'movie-genre' ),
  ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_movie_genre_taxonomy', 0 );

?>
```

I've readed many posts about that, tried many plugins with "slug remover" but nothing help me. Maybe you can look in my code and say what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found following code, made it a plugin (you have to create a php file and give it a name,copy code below into that file and place it in your plugins folder).
 
It is not my code so therefore I put references to the author and original source-code and links to github.

You have to (re)set your permalinks after activating this plugin by going to:
*Settings > Permalinks in the admin panel and click Save Changes*

*NOTE:*
 Your function which creates the cpt is imho not 100% correct (ie. using twice `'rewrite'=>`, and using a text-domain or don't but rather do not use it partly as you do),
maybe re-creating it is a better option? [Online engine to create a CPT](http://generatewp.com/post-type/)
*Just a hint, when using custom post type's make it a plugin and put them in your plugins folder. (So after switching theme's(ie. to test) you still have your custom post at hand.*

*I tested it not local but they say it works*
I can not guarantee that there won't be issues with it in the near future because it is(at least seem to me) rare to leave slugs out the way you want.

```
 <?php 
  /*
   Plugin Name:  Rewrite CPT Movie slug
   Description:  Removes slug from published post type permalinks.(Only affect our CPT though) / Have WordPress match postname to any of our public post types (movie, page, post)
   Author:       Charles
   License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
   License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */
 /**
  * Remove the slug from published post permalinks. Only affect our CPT though.
  *
  * @author Kellen Mace <http://kellenmace.com>
  * @link   http://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/
  * @see    https://gist.github.com/kellenmace/65d100fa6c76d249c53f#file-remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks-2-php    
  */
 function remove_cpt_slug_191875( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

      if ( 'movie' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
          return $post_link;
      }

      $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

      return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'remove_cpt_slug_191875', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Have WordPress match postname to any of our public post types (movie, page, post)
 * All of our public post types can have /post-name/ as the slug, so they better be unique across all posts
 * By default, core only accounts for posts and pages where the slug is /post-name/
 *
 * @author Kellen Mace <http://kellenmace.com>
 * @link   http://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/
 * @see    https://gist.github.com/kellenmace/b39553b3c7243ff62040#file-remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-php
 */
function parse_request_trick_191875( $query ) {
     // Only noop the main query
     if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
     return;

    // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
    if ( 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
    return;
    }

   // 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, otherwise the page rule will match
   if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
         $query->set( 'post_type', array(  'movie', 'post', 'page' ) );
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'parse_request_trick_191875' );
```